# Python code using Flask framework doesn't work and I don't know why

Tags: python

I copy-pasted code from an online tutorial video and somehow it doesn't work;
**Code from my FlaskProject_1.py file:**

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

posts = [
    {
        'author': 'Corey Schafer',
        'title': 'Blog Post 1',
        'content': 'First post content',
        'date_posted': 'April 20, 2018'
    }
    {
        'author': 'Jane Doe',
        'title': 'Blog Post 2',
        'content': 'Second post content',
        'date_posted': 'April 21, 2018'
    }
]

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':     
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Code from my home.html file:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <p>By {{ post.author }} on {{ post.date_posted }}</p>
        <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

**Code from my about.html file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>About Page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**Running the code using CMD on port http://127.0.0.1:5000/, this is what I get:**

```
E:\IT\Python Projects\Flask Project 01>flask run
 * Serving Flask app 'FlaskProject_1' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\sfic man\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\sfic man\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Sfic Man\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\sfic man\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 990, in main
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:])
  File "c:\users\sfic man\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 596, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\sfic man\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1062, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\users\sfic man\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1668, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\users\sfic man\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\users\sfic man\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 763, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\sfic man\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\sfic man\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 763, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\sfic man\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 845, in run_command
    app = DispatchingApp(info.load_app, use_eager_loading=eager_loading)
  File "c:\users\sfic man\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 321, in __init__
    self._load_unlocked()
  File "c:\users\sfic man\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 346, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "c:\users\sfic man\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 402, in load_app
    app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
  File "c:\users\sfic man\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 256, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "E:\IT\Python Projects\Flask Project 01\FlaskProject_1.py", line 23
    {
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The http://127.0.0.1:5000/ port just displays the "Hmmm… can't reach this page127.0.0.1 refused to connect." error message.

Comment: You are missing `,` in your `posts` list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Except in extraneous situations, questions involving syntax errors are usually not great questions for Stack Overflow. Although these questions are easily solvable, they often do not provide value to the community due to how specific to your situation they are. These types of questions are technically against the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely because of  the missing comma separating the two posts in the posts list:

```
posts = [
    {
        'author': 'Corey Schafer',
        'title': 'Blog Post 1',
        'content': 'First post content',
        'date_posted': 'April 20, 2018'
    }
    {
        'author': 'Jane Doe',
        'title': 'Blog Post 2',
        'content': 'Second post content',
        'date_posted': 'April 21, 2018'
    }
]
```

should read:

```
posts = [
    {
        'author': 'Corey Schafer',
        'title': 'Blog Post 1',
        'content': 'First post content',
        'date_posted': 'April 20, 2018'
    },
    {
        'author': 'Jane Doe',
        'title': 'Blog Post 2',
        'content': 'Second post content',
        'date_posted': 'April 21, 2018'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this code block:

```
posts = [
    {
        'author': 'Corey Schafer',
        'title': 'Blog Post 1',
        'content': 'First post content',
        'date_posted': 'April 20, 2018'
    }
    {
        'author': 'Jane Doe',
        'title': 'Blog Post 2',
        'content': 'Second post content',
        'date_posted': 'April 21, 2018'
    }
]
```

List items are separated by commas.  You need a comma after the first dictionary.

Comment: It doesn't look like you fixed the typo in this answer

Comment: @spicy.dll You're right.  I quoted that block of code to show where the problem is, then I _described_ how to fix it.